# Multiple Expandable list view Titanuim

Tags: titanium, expandablelistview

I am developing an application for **android** devices using **Titanium Appcelerator**., I need list view that should be like *Expandable list*, like **children within the childrens**, (Example: 3 storey)..

I went through this **[link](https://gist.github.com/rileydutton/946647)** and worked for 2 storeys and when i attempted to make 3 storey , it give me a bug, I can insert a *new row dynamically* , But i couldn't access the custom variables. What have i made mistake...

[Reference link](https://gist.github.com/rileydutton/946647)

```
     //Third Row
var row3 = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title : "User Management",
    font : {
        fontSize : '18dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    height : 'auto',
    isparent : true,
    opened : false,
    color : 'black',
    borderRadius : 5,
    borderColor : 'black',
    borderWidth : 1,
    sub : [{
        className : 'children',
        title : "Approve Registration",
        isparent : true,
        opened : false,
        color : 'brown',
        left : 20,
        sub : [{
            className : 'child1',
            title : "Cross Connect",
            color : 'blue',
            left : 25,
            font : {
                fontSize : '15dp'
            },
            isparent : false,
        }, {
            className : 'child1',
            title : "Smart Hands",
            color : 'blue',
            left : 25,
            font : {
                fontSize : '15dp'
            },
            isparent : false,
        }],
        height : 'auto',
        font : {
            fontSize : '15dp'
        },
    }, {
        className : 'child',
        title : "Invite Portal Users",
        color : 'blue',
        left : 20,
        font : {
            fontSize : '15dp'
        },
        isparent : false,
    }, {
        className : 'child',
        title : "Add Users",
        color : 'blue',
        left : 20,
        font : {
            fontSize : '15dp'
        },
        isparent : false,
    }]
});

rowData.push(row3);


tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('isparent...' + e.row.isparent);
});
```

I can get values to the first parent,But when i clicked the *dynamically added children data*
i getting "**undefined**"

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorry for such late reply, but have you tried using the getParent() function to get the parent object of any element.
2. Actually, getParent() is not listed anywhere in Titanium documentation, but you can use this function anywhere to get any number of levels of parent,grandparent of a child.
   Hope it would help you & try creating the layout using Alloy as it will provide you more flexibility & a clean view to know the parents & child levels.